# Create Folder Structure to Organize Content in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I have many pages in the content section of Umbraco but some of the pages I would like to organize for departmental reference not necessarily for hierarchical site reference.  For example, my pages might be A, B, C, D ... Z on the website  but on the backend we have various teams that need their content grouped together.  i.e. Team 1 folder has A-G in it.  Team 2 folder has H-Q.  Team 3 has R-Z in it.  How can this be achieved so instead of seeing all the content on the root of the content page I only see these 3 team folders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to be carefull in achieving this. When you create new nodes under your `Home` root node, eg new pages or folders, they are referenced with an url.

So If you have a page called `A`, this will be accessed using the url `http://www.example.com/a`. When you create folders to organize pages and you place page `A` under `HQ`, then your page will now be accessed by `http://www.example.com/hq/a`.

After that you can use url rewriting rules to avaid these folders indications in your url but that will be messed up if you have many pages.

I will suggest if you don't want to see these folder indications in your url, to just add all the nodes under your `Home` node and using `Permission` to allow/disallow departments to the nodes.

If you don't care about the folder indications in your url, let me know then  I will edit this answer with the solution to achieve this.

**EDIT**

How to add folder structure in your content nodes.

*Step 1*

Create a new `Document Type` called `Content Folder`.

1. Go to `Settings` > `Document Types` > click on the 3 dots > `Create`.
2. Give it the name `Content Folder`.
3. As icon select the folder icon
4. Add a new property `Redirect` with alias `umbracoRedirect` with type `Content Picker`
5. Save changes

> The builtin property `umbracoRedirect` is used to redirect one node to
>   another using its id. So for each folder set this property to the first child page.

*Step 2*

Allow your child node types in this folder.

1. Go to the structure tab of your `Content Folder` property
2. Check the child types that you want to allow under this folder
3. Save changes

*Step 3*

Allow this folder under your root `Home` node.

1. Go to the structure tab of your `Home` root property
2. Check the `ContentFolder`type to allow as a child
3. Save changes

*Step 4*

Add you folder structure and add pages.

1. Go to your content
2. Add a new folder under your root node of type `Content Folder`
3. Give it the name `HQ`
4. Add a new page called `A` that's allowed under your folder
5. In your `HQ` set the `Redirect` property to your first `A` page
6. Do this for all your folders and pages
7. Save changes and publish

And thats it!

Comment: I am ok with seeing the folder names. how can I achive this.

Comment: This worked great. When I implemented this solution the folder names don't show up in the URL for me which is interesting.  Any idea why that might be.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this is with a  custom URL Provider and Content Finder. This is where you create a new provider for working out the URL of the pages on your site, overriding the default folder structure.

You can add your own logic out strip out folders from the URLS, so /folder/a/content could become /folder/content. Obviously you'd need to be careful that the other folders don't contain items with the same names, or you may get the wrong content returned.

The advantage of a URL Provider is that whenever you call the Umbraco methods to get the URL of a content item, you'll ALWAYS get the custom URL.

The content finder is a way for the site to match the modified URLs back to the original content. You'll need both for it to work.

[Here](http://24days.in/umbraco/2014/urlprovider-and-contentfinder/) is a link to an in depth article about using these two in conjunction in an Umbraco site.